# VSCode debugger is misaligned

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

Since this morning, my VSCode debugger has alignment problems (when debugging step by step highlighted code does not follow "real" code). I've tried to uninstall VSCode and reinstall from fresh. Problem is still present. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I'm running VSCode on MacOS High Sierra (10.13.1)

VSCode info:

```
Version: 1.49.0
Commit: e790b931385d72cf5669fcefc51cdf65990efa5d
Date: 2020-09-10T17:39:53.251Z
Electron: 9.2.1
Chrome: 83.0.4103.122
Node.js: 12.14.1
V8: 8.3.110.13-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 17.2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

For now, the only way I found to solve my problem is to rename the problematic file and copy its content into a new file named the same as original. File was probably corrupted for some reason.